# Compartir enlace + texto + imagen en whatsapp desde swift

Tags: ios, swift2, whatsapp

Estoy haciendo una app, que es un lector de rss.

Lo que quiero es que se pueda compartir una noticia por whatsapp, y que los datos que se compartan sean:

- Una imagen
- Un titulo
- Un enlace

De momento tengo esto:

```
let urlString = "Hello Friends, Sharing some data here..."
        let urlStringEncoded = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
        //URLHostAllowedCharacterSet
        urlToGo  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded!)")
        print(urlToGo)
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(urlToGo!){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(urlToGo!)
        }else{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "No tienes instalado Whatsapp en el dispositivo", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Como puedo hacer para añadir un enlace, un texto y una imagen?

Hay alguna libreria con la que lo pueda realizar

Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar UIActivityViewController para compartir la imagen, el texto y el enlace.

```html
NSString *textToShare = @"Enter your text to be shared";
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, image];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Alguien preguntó lo mismo en stackoverflow en inglés: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35745644/4955542)

@AlbertoMier Pregunté en la ruta precedente, si podía servir el código para Swift 2 y me han respondido con esta parte de código por si lo quieres probar.

let shareText = "Hello, world!" if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage") { let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, image], applicationActivities: []) presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) }

Te dejo un enlace de una app hecha en swift que dice que hace eso que quieres. La app la han actualizado hace 2 días seguro que te sirve para swift 2. (https://github.com/LauraSempere/meme-app)

Comment: ¿No te sirve @AlbertoMier?

Comment: Yo lo necesito en `swift 2` @MarcLemien

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta @AlbertoMier

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probare @MarcLemien